# Custom spinner adapter with prompt title gives a white space above the prompt title

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I need to create a spinner with spinner Mode="Dialog".In the dialog i need the prompt text to have a different background.I was successfully able to build one,but the prompt title background has a white space above it.

[image: spinner pop up looks like this]
I need to remove this white space.Is there a way to do it.

My custom adapter looks like

```
    package com.cws.cwsdashboard1.fragments;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
     import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.cws.cwsdashboard1.R;

     import java.util.List;

    public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements 
    SpinnerAdapter {
     List<String> vehicles;
     Context context;

    public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, List<String> vehicles) {
        this.vehicles = vehicles;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return vehicles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return vehicles.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view =  View.inflate(context, R.layout.vehicle_spinner, null);
        view.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_text);
        if(position==0){
            textView.setText(vehicles.get(position+1));
        }
        else {
            textView.setText(vehicles.get(position));
        }
        textView.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
        return textView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view;

        if (position == 0){

            view =  View.inflate(context, R.layout.vehicle_prompt, null);
            view.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
           // view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_prompt);
            textView.setText(vehicles.get(position));
            textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });

        }else {
            view =  View.inflate(context, R.layout.vehicle_dropdown, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_dropdown);
            textView.setText(vehicles.get(position));
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

vehicle_dropdown.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/vehicle_dropdown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_reg"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

vehicle_prompt.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/vehicle_prompt"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="At res"
        android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_reg"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center" />


</LinearLayout>
```

vehicle_spinner.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_text"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:text=""
    android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_reg"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```

Comment: You are facing this is issue because Spinner internally using `AlertDialog` class when you are making `android:spinnerMode="dialog"` and It has some hard coded padding.

Comment: Do you suggest that it can't be changed?

Comment: I think in this case we can't change/remove that default padding.I suggest you to create custom dialog with listing and manage it like spinner does.

Comment: Could you suggest some example to do the same

Comment: Yes sure,Please checkout this [link][1] ,they have developed custom dialog with listing and manged listener for item click. 


  [1]: https://demonuts.com/android-custom-dialog-with-listview/

Answer (score -1):

You can remove them by overriding the getDropDownView() method of your custom adapter. If you are not using a custom adapter, I would suggest you to use a custom adapter.

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    parent.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return convertView;
}
```

If you are also doing some other stuff for customising your drop-down views, you can still use it like this:

```
@Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        parent.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        View v = super.getDropDownView(position, null, parent);
        
        //Do your work here
        
        return v;
    }
```